# c# winforms button and richtextbox

Tags: c#, winforms

I made ​​a winform with 1 richtextbox and two buttons,
and I hope that when I click on the yes button , it will show a method soal2 in richtextbox1  , and then when I click again it will show soal3 , how to do that?
[this is my design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sQ1Jx.jpg)

```
    public void soal1()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "Hemofilia is xxxxx";
    }

    public void soal2()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "xxxxxxx";
    }

    public void soal3()
    {
        richTextBox1.Text = "yyyyyy";
    }

    private void Quiz1_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        soal1();
    }

    private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
/* ... */
bool alreadyShownSoal2 = false; 

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if(alreadyShownSoal2)
       soal3();
    else
       soal2();
    alreadyShownSoal2 = true;
}
```

or

```
/* ... */

bool alreadyShownSoal2 = false; 
public void soal2()
{
    if(alreadyShownSoal2)
       soal3();
    else 
       richTextBox1.Text = "xxxxxxx";
    alreadyShownSoal2 = true;
}

/* ... */

private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    soal2();
}
```

This is an absolutely terrible design, but unless you give more specifications... it'd definitely do what you are asking

Comment: @Draken once you spend some time answering questions in S.O. you learn to read through "that english" quickly ;-)

Comment: i'm sorry for my english

Comment: @Suci0605 it's actually more a thing of thinking twice rather than bad english redaction... for example: `it will show a method soal2 in richtextbox1` is not bad english, but it's pretty much incorrect, it doesn't `show a method in a richtextbox` (I just guessed what you meant there). Asking better questions will help you get better answers :-)

Comment: Anyway, was this answer what you were asking?

Comment: @Suci0605 if you think the answer solved your problem, [mark it as accepted](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) :-)